# scrollable div inside container

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/fMs67/. I'd like to make the div2 to respect the size of div1 and scroll the contents of div3.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

UPDATE-1:

This is the more advanced case that I oversimplified when I asked the question: http://jsfiddle.net/Wcgvt/. I need somehow that header+it's sibling div to not overflow the parent div's size.

Comment: Hi TCC - thank you for asking! Actually my case was a bit more complex than that - I added UPDATE-1 with a new fiddler.

Comment: What you're trying to do is very hard without specifying hard heights, i.e., set d3-2 to max height of d3's height minus d3-1's height.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Adding `position: relative` to the parent, and a `max-height:100%`; on div2 works.

```html
<body>
  <div id="div1" style="height: 500px;position:relative;">
    <div id="div2" style="max-height:100%;overflow:auto;border:1px solid red;">
      <div id="div3" style="height:1500px;border:5px solid yellow;">hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>​
```

---

Update: The following shows the "updated" example and answer. http://jsfiddle.net/Wcgvt/181/

The secret there is to use `box-sizing: border-box`, and some padding to make the second div height 100%, but move it's content down 50px. Then wrap the content in a div with `overflow: auto` to contain the scrollbar. Pay attention to z-indexes to keep all the text selectable - hope this helps, several years later.

Answer (score 20):

If you put `overflow: scroll` on a fixed height `div`, the `div` will scroll  if the contents take up too much space.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of `overflow:auto`, try     `overflow-y:auto`.  Should work like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you are wanting?

```html
<body>
  <div id="div1" style="height: 500px;">
    <div id="div2" style="height: inherit; overflow: auto; border:1px solid red;">
      <div id="div3" style="height:1500px;border:5px solid yellow;">hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fMs67/1/

Answer (score 3):

i have just added (overflow:scroll;) in (div3) with fixed height.

see the fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/fMs67/10/

Answer (score 2):

I created an enhanced version, based on Trey Copland's fiddle, that I think is more like what you wanted.  Added here for future reference to those who come here later.
[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mcolynuck/g0z8pn8v/1/)

```
    <body>
<style>
.modal {
  height: 390px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
.heading {
  padding: 10px;
}
.content {
  height: 300px;
  overflow:auto;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.scrollable {
  height: 1200px;
  border: 5px solid yellow;

}
.footer {
  height: 2em;
  padding: .5em;
}
</style>
      <div class="modal">
          <div class="heading">
            <h4>Heading</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
              <div class="scrollable" >hello</div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer">
            Footer
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is as this example:

```
<div>
   <div style=' height:300px;'>
     SOME LOGO OR CONTENT HERE
   </div>
   <div style='overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: scroll;'> 
      THIS IS SOME TEXT
   </DIV>
```

You can see the test cases on:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Answer (score -1):

```js
function start() {
 document.getElementById("textBox1").scrollTop +=5;
    scrolldelay = setTimeout(function() {start();}, 40);
}

function stop(){
 clearTimeout(scrolldelay);
}

function reset(){
 var loc = document.getElementById("textBox1").scrollTop;
 document.getElementById("textBox1").scrollTop -= loc;
 clearTimeout(scrolldelay);
}
//adjust height of paragraph in css
//element textbox in div
//adjust speed at scrolltop and start
```