# How to hide scrollbar on mobile browser?

Tags: html, css

I have tried this:

```
html, body {
            scrollbar-width: none; /* firefox */
            -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 10+ */
        }

::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 0px;
            display: none; /* Safari and Chrome */
        }
```

And it works well on the common PC Browser but when it changes to mobile it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Finally I did it according to this: [scrollable div inside container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9811485/14691761)

By making 3 div container the scrollbar will inside the middle div

I set the body

```
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

the outside div

```
height:screen.availHeight //this just a fake code I use blazor to do this
overflow: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This make sure there will be a fixed height box for the content and the scrollbar will not show at the right of the page when the content height overflow

Then the middle div

```
overflow: scroll
```

when the height of the content in the inside div overflow,there will be a scrollbar inside the middle div

and by setting this

```
html, body {
    scrollbar-width: none; /* firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 10+ */
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;/* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

the scrollbar will be hide both on pc and mobile

Answer (score 1):

try this hide's it on screens less than 375px

```
body{
  height: 1000vh
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px){
     ::-webkit-scrollbar {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
   }
}
```